# Dialog is not a function in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

My _layout.cshtml contains:

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/all.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In Index.cshtml try to:

```
<div id="dialog_1">
    <label>Something</label>
</div>
<script> 
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog_1").dialog();    
})</script>
```

Get: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem: after including jQuery UI package need bundle the required files and refer to the bundles.

Answer (score 0):

Either include minified version of jquery ui file or actual version of file, you have added both - that is wrong:

Either remove `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"` or `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js"`

Try this:

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/all.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: set src like `src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js")'` - check quotes properly

Comment: I got all of these files in Chrome debugger properly.